# Android premium HERE SDK - offline maps saving to external storage

Tags: here-api

How can i save the **offline Here maps** to **external sd card**?
Is it even possible?
Than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to set isolated disk cache in SDK.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/topics/map-service.html